# Noise reduction for 2D advection scheme

Tags: matlab, noise

I am modelling the path of a rock deposited onto a glacier and its englacial flow with the ice within the glacier in MATLAB. I am doing this with the 2D advection equation. However, I do get some unwanted artefacts / noise in my results, especially at the left of the attached image. I tried a 2D median filter, but this lead to bad results (second image). Does anyone have an idea of my options?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share some properties on the noise? What generates it?

Comment: Hi, in your model, is it possible to treat the rock as a point and calculate the trajectory instead of a density distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to grayscale and try morphological operations, such as [imerode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is only 1 rock, you could find the peak, and set the value to zero at other coordinates.